# How to merge two objects in PHP

Tags: php, array-merge, array-push

I have problem when try to merge two array in PHP. For example I have:

```
(
    [k] => Array
        (
            [aaaa] => 11
            [bbb] => 22
        )

)
```

And an array two follow:

```
(
    [k] => Array
        (
            [ccc] => 333
            [dddd] => 444
            [eeee] => 555
            [ffff] => 666
        )
)
```

I want to merge two arrays above as follows:

```
(
    [k] => Array
        (
            [aaaa] => 11
            [bbb] => 22
            [ccc] => 333
            [dddd] => 444
            [eeee] => 555
            [ffff] => 666
        )
)
```

When I try to array_push above as follows:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [k] => Array
                (
                    [aaaa] => 11
                    [bbb] => 22
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [k] => Array
            (
                [ccc] => 333
                [dddd] => 444
                [eeee] => 555
                [ffff] => 666
            )
    )
)
```

So what can I will do, anyone?

Comment: `array_push` does not merge arrays, you should loop over values of first  array and `array_merge` it with corresponding values of second array

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$arr1 = Array("ccc" => 333, "dddd" => 444, "eeee" => 555, "ffff" => 666);
$arr2 = Array("aaaa" => 11, "bbb" => 22, "ccc" => 333, "dddd" => 444, "eeee" => 555, "ffff" => 666);
```

> Return as array

```
$arr3 = array_merge((array) $arr1, (array) $arr2);
print_r($arr3);
```

> output

```
Array ( [ccc] => 333 [dddd] => 444 [eeee] => 555 [ffff] => 666 [aaaa] => 11 [bbb] => 22 )
```

> Return as object

```
$arr3 = (object)array_merge((array) $arr1, (array) $arr2);
print_r($arr3);
```

> output

```
stdClass Object ( [ccc] => 333 [dddd] => 444 [eeee] => 555 [ffff] => 666 [aaaa] => 11 [bbb] => 22 )
?>
```

Comment: array(1) {
  ["k"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["aaaa"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["bbb"]=>
    string(2) "22"
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["k"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["ccc"]=>
    string(3) "333"
    ["dddd"]=>
    string(3) "444"
    ["eeee"]=>
    string(3) "555"
    ["ffff"]=>
    string(3) "666"
  }
}

Comment: why should I check my friend I have  no objection with your answer and even I did not comment anything on your answer.

Comment: @NikolaGavric does any issue with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `array_merge($array1, $array2)`

**EDIT:**

For multidimensional arrays you gotta loop through them like this:

```
$oneArr = [];
foreach($arrays as $arr) {
    array_merge($arr, $oneArr);
}
print_r($oneArr);
```

Comment: does not matter

Comment: How do you mean does not matter? Thats how you merge 2 arrays into a single array

Comment: array(1) {
  ["k"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["aaaa"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["bbb"]=>
    string(2) "22"
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["k"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["ccc"]=>
    string(3) "333"
    ["dddd"]=>
    string(3) "444"
    ["eeee"]=>
    string(3) "555"
    ["ffff"]=>
    string(3) "666"
  }
}

Comment: Reminder, you need to assign the array_merge to a variable. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you so much I solved.

```
                                        <?php 
                                    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM fiyatlar");
                                    $i=1;
                                    $veriler = array();
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                                        $veriler = (unserialize($row['icerik']));

                                    foreach ($veriler['k'] as $key => $value) {
                                    ?>
```